# Redirect with posting xml data in JAX-RS

Tags: java, redirect, jax-rs

How can I redirect to a page along with posting XML data to it.

I am able to redirect to the page and send post data to it by **including hidden form fields** and **automatically submitting the form using Javascript** to the required page but I need to send XML Data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to post Form data + a xml content right?

Comment: I only need to post xml content ..